# How to declare a static member in a Powershell 5 class?

Tags: class, powershell, static, powershell-5.0

If I have a PS 5 class and I want a static member in it - how do I declare it?

```
Class Foo {
  [string] $Bar = 'static member'
}
```

So I could reference it without an instance like this

```
Write-Host [Foo]::Bar
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PowerShell 5 added a `static` keyword for this:

```powershell
static [string] $Bar = 'static member'
```

Demo:

```powershell
PS > class Foo {
>>     static [string] $Bar = 'static member'
>> }   
PS > [Foo]::Bar
static member
PS >
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response!